# Stack toolbars and tabpanels in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, toolbar, tabbar

I'm practicing with Sencha Touch.  I created a simple tabbar that's docked at the bottom of the screen.  Here's my code:

```
Ext.setup({
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
    icon: 'icon.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,
    onReady: function() {
        Ext.regModel('ListItem', {
            fields: [{name: 'text', type: 'string'}]
        });

        var d1 = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
                            model: 'ListItem',
                            root:{text:'D1',items:{}},
                            proxy: {
                                      type: 'ajax',
                                      reader: {
                                              type: 'tree',
                                              root: 'items'
                                          }
                            }
        });
            var d2 = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
                            model: 'ListItem',
                            root:{text:'D2',items:{}},
                            proxy: {
                                      type: 'ajax',
                                      reader: {
                                              type: 'tree',
                                              root: 'items'
                                          }
                            }
        }); 
        tabBar = new Ext.TabPanel({
            id:'tabPanel',
            fullscreen:true,
            tabBar: {
                dock: 'bottom'
            },
            items:[
                new Ext.NestedList({dock:'left',title:'title',iconCls:'home', width:'350', store:d1}),
                new Ext.NestedList({dock:'left',title:'title',iconCls:'home', width:'350', store:d2})
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

What I want to do next is create a toolbar directly on top of the tab bar.  This toolbar will print some text (which I'll eventually use to create a scrolling newsfeed).  How do I add a toolbar directly on top of the tab bar?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
tabBar = new Ext.TabPanel({
            id:'tabPanel',
            fullscreen:true,
            tabBar: {
                dock: 'bottom'
            },
            items:[
                new Ext.NestedList({
                    dock:'left',
                    title:'title',
                    iconCls:'home', 
                    width:'350', 
                    store:d1,
                    dockedItems: [{
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        dock: 'bottom',
                        items: [{
                            text: 'Docked to the bottom'
                        }]
                    }]
                }),
                new Ext.NestedList({dock:'left',title:'title',iconCls:'home', width:'350', store:d2})
            ]
        });
```

The first tab now have a toolbar just above the tabbar

Comment: Oh, i thought i got it working.  But how do i make that toolbar "persistent" so that it also shows for the second tab in the tabbar?

Comment: I think you need to add a dockedItems config to you other NestedList. I can't think of another way of doing it even though the way seems redundant.

Comment: i did find an ugly way, and will post the hacky solution once i get around to it.  TOoo many deadliness!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing around with something similar tonight, trying to add a message bar above the tab bar.  I found a nice way to do it using the initComponent method (I'm using lazy instantiation and Ext.extend to create xtypes).  Here's a modified version of your tabBar code that worked for me:

```
tabBar = new Ext.TabPanel({
        id:'tabPanel',
        fullscreen:true,
        tabBar: {
            dock: 'bottom'
        },
        items:[
            new Ext.NestedList({dock:'left',title:'title',iconCls:'home', width:'350', store:d1}),
            new Ext.NestedList({dock:'left',title:'title',iconCls:'home', width:'350', store:d2})
        ]
        listeners: {
              beforerender: function(){
                  this.addDocked({
                      html: 'hello world',
                      dock: 'bottom'
                  });
              }
        }
    });
```